# BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost in GXT

Tags: google-chrome, gwt-rpc, gxt

. . . 
     i created a gxt project and i made RPC mechanism for Retrieve data But it works fine at first time even RPC call also. 
But after that it doesnt while clear cache memmory it works in mozilla but not in crome.

My Error is follows help me to resolve this. . . . . . .

```
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost
    at 

com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelException: Invalid message type CHECK_VERSIONS

    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:303)
    at 

com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)

    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```